# Firefox flicker 3D transforms

Tags: firefox, css, 3d, css-transforms

This template I have made using CSS3 3D transforms is flickering like crazy in FireFox 15 (and possibly older versions? It did seem to be fine a few months ago before an update). I've managed to stop the flickering by removing the container's `perspective` property, but that's not ideal. If I delete all the child element with Firebug, the problem persists.

Any ideas? It works as expected in all other browsers! I realise this technology is new and unstable, but the flickering is pretty awful in Firefox and absolutely fine in Chrome and Safari.

http://iamalexkempton.net/themes/vFlip_v1-1-preview/template/index1.php

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Implementations by browsers of CSS3 properties, especially transforms, and very especially 3D transforms, is experimental. Likely you've hit an issue with FF's implementation. That said, others with similar issues have reported success adding `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the elements being transformed

Comment: Perhaps [bug 749634](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749634) refers to the problems you are seeing? If so, it looks like it's assigned, so it should hopefully be fixed in a future release.

Comment: awesome site! Massive flickering for me in Firefox v22. Guess you haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: Thanks. It's just one of those weird ones that clearly isn't stable. None of the browsers are really dealing with perspective in the same way, along with all that crazy "backface-visibility" too. The downsides of messing around with new technologies!

Answer (score 1):

Translate3d is buggy (if that's what you're using). RotateY should work fine. It at least solved my flickering and weird rotation.

See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769892

Offtopic: Nice site! Works fine here in FF.

Answer (score 0):

use `perspective: 1000px;` on the containder of a element with the transform should work

Regards